# Checking console messages in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have local file where I can check if correct messages have been sent through console.
I can see the messages through cypress and count them but it seems that I can't check the actual message.

Code Example:

```
it(`Checking Error Text in:`, () => {

cy.visit('../testmessages.html', {
onBeforeLoad(win) {
    cy.stub(win.console, 'log').as('consoleLog')},
})

cy.get('button').click()
cy.get("@consoleLog").should('be.calledThrice')

//here I would like to confirm that message contains "Id" etc 
})})})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, if you use `cy.stub()` you *can't* see the message in the console any more, because it blocks the call.

A `cy.spy()` would be better, then any `console.log()` you add for debugging aren't swallowed up by the stub.

If you save the result of the cy.spy(), you can use methods on it to extract the call data collected.

```js
let spy;
Cypress.on('window:before:load', (win) => {
  spy = cy.spy(win.console, 'log');
});

cy.visit('../testmessages.html')   
cy.get('button').click()            // console.log('hello', 'world')

cy.then(() => {
  const calls = spy.getCalls();
  expect(calls.length).to.eq(3)
  expect(calls[1].args).to.deep.eq(['hello', 'world'])
})
```

Answer (score 0):

With a stub, you can check what was passed to the function with something like this

```
cy.get(@consoleLog).should("have.been.calledWith", "Expected console message");
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to get warning from my console and also verifying text of those warnings. Below is my code:

```
Cypress.on('window:before:load', (win)=>{
 cy.spy(win.console, 'warn').as('consoleWarning')
})
//some code here
cy.window().then((win)=>{
 expect(win.console.warn).to.have.callCount(1)
 cy.get('@consoleWarning').should('have.been.calledWith','text')
})
```